# How to extract data from an ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to be able to get different array values in my ajax callback function, how would I do this? Im trying this atm..

```
function sendFeedback() {
$.post({
       url: 'send-feedback.php', 
       dataType: "json", 
       data: {
       user_id : this.bb_user, 
       star_count : this.limit, 
       feedback : document.feedback_form.feedback.value,
       set_anon : document.feedback_form.set_anon.checked
    }, success: function(output) {
    alert(output.coms[1]);
    // make it alert index 1 from the array??
}});
closeFeedback();
}
```

then in send-feedback.php

```
        $coms = array("value1", "value2");
        echo json_encode($coms);
```

i havent got a clue, thanks.

Comment: do ypu see something in firebug?

Comment: just `output[1]`. there is no `coms`

Comment: Show your JSON response.

Comment: Chrome and Safari have a great console for logging objects and inspecting their structure. `console.log(output)` and you'll know how to access what you want to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try this if it will work..

```
success: function(output) {
   var data = eval('(' + output + ')');
   alert(data[0]);
}
```

let me know..

---

did you made it like this right?

```
function sendFeedback() {
  $.post({
    url: 'send-feedback.php', 
    dataType: "json", 
    data: {
    user_id : this.bb_user, 
    star_count : this.limit, 
    feedback : document.feedback_form.feedback.value,
    set_anon : document.feedback_form.set_anon.checked
  },
  success: function(output) {
    var data = eval('(' + output + ')');
    alert(data[0]);
  }});

  closeFeedback();
}
```

Comment: it doesnt even do the actual function unless i do it the simpler way  $.post('send-feedback.php', {
     user_id : this.bb_user, 
  }, function(output) {
  alert(output[1]);
 }); which is really annoying

Comment: if i do it like that then it returns the single character like data[2] returns 'v' but i think i need to use the dataType: "json" but i cant cos when i change it to the other way it doesnt work atall

Comment: ow but if i do what you said with the eval() on the simpler version then it returns the right thing

Comment: so are you able to extract the data you want now?

Comment: yes cheers :) but im still wondering why when i use the more complicated version it doesnt work at all ( the one i provided in the question)

Comment: lol what you put above i cant make work i used the "simpler version" as i call it and it seems to make it work for some reason > `function sendFeedback() {
 $.post('send-feedback.php', {
     user_id : this.bb_user, 
     star_count : this.limit, 
     feedback : document.feedback_form.feedback.value,
     set_anon : document.feedback_form.set_anon.checked
  }, function(output) {
     var data = eval('(' + output + ')');
   alert(data[1]);
 });
 closeFeedback();
}`

Comment: hmm.. i honestly can't tell cause I haven't used function yet.. though i'm glad I made a small help :)